How can I use the same mesh (of a surface) from one mesh file created by Gmsh in part of another solid?
I am trying to model a general contact problem. I require the meshes to match at the interface. How does one make meshes to match on two surfaces (interface between two solids objects) in two different 3d mesh created by GMSH ? I am using the python API of GMSH. I am using linear tetrahedron elements. Hence, we have triangles at the interface. I understand from other posts that I can use translation command to copy mesh within the same mesh/solid object as below
translation = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
gmsh.model.mesh.setPeriodic(2, [face2], [face1], translation)

But I am interested in generalizing this. Ideally I want to create the first object (3D). Mesh it. Create another object (3D). Load the first mesh into this and impose some constraint (2D surface mesh) in meshing of object 2.
